# Looking for a proven way to call functions in a ssh command(ssh is written outside of functions)

Tags: bash, shell

I am not an expert in shell scripting but I have written a code to fetch server logs based on some user input which is unique ID.
My script structure looks like below:

```
function liveLogs(){

here -> logic to "read a .properties file line by line that contains all the directories to be searched"
grep the userinput ID in all directories

}
```

one more fucntion archiveLogs() like above to search archived logs.

I am calling above functions in main block within the same script like below:

```
if [[ $1 == "ARCHIVE" ]]
then
ARCHIVE="archiveLogs" --> assigning function to varibale
else
LIVE="liveLogs" --> assigning function to varibale

OutputLogFilePath = "a/Logfile.txt"

if [[ ! -z ${LIVE} ]]

ssh -q -T username@host "bash -s -- $ID" < ${LIVE} 2>&1 | tee -a ${OutputLogFilePath}
else 
ssh -q -T username@host "bash -s -- $ID" < ${ARCHIVE} 2>&1 | tee -a ${OutputLogFilePath}
fi
```

for above ssh commands, on terminal it throws --> "no such file for directory"

based on my R&D, it is mentioned that we cannot directly call function on remote hosts.
I tried some other commands like

```
- declare -f
typeset -f
<<-EOF typeset-f funcname EOF
export -f fucntion and parallel --env
```

but nothing is working for me.
Can someone please help here?

---

Below is the revised post for more details.
This is main block I am trying to get working.
Everything from "if"  till "done" is the main block code.

```sh
if [[ $1 == "HIST" ]]  
then  

    ARCHIVE="archiveLogs"
else  

    LIVE="liveLogs"

showmenus --> #function to display selection menu on terminal  
readoptions  --> #readoptions is a function with two cases to read unique ID as user input (Single input and multiple inputs)    

read userinput  
SERVERLIST="$userinput"  

while read -r line  

    do
        SERVERLIST=${line}
        
        if [[ ! -z ${LIVE} ]]
        then
        echo ${ARCHIVE}
        #changes I did to ssh as per your comments. Did'nt think of need for fucntion some_entrypoint()
        ssh -q -T fircoadm@${line} "bash -s" <<-EOF 2>&1 | tee -a ${OutputLogFilePath}
        $(declare -f readoptions liveLogs)
        $(declare -p ARCHIVE)
        EOF
        else 
        echo ${LIVE}
        ssh -q -T fircoadm@${line} "bash -s" <<-EOF 2>&1 | tee -a ${OutputLogFilePath}
        $(declare -f readoptions archiveLogs) #readoptions is a function to read unique ID as user input
        $(declare -p LIVE)
        EOF
        fi
    done < ${SERVERLIST}
```

Output:
I have 6 remote hosts, so on terminal it prints echo command (declared above ssh) 6 times.
Seems loop executed on all remote hosts but my code in functions does not work on remote hosts.

Comment: Please [format your code sections *in code format*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to make them readable; I tried to sort them out, but wasn't sure what was supposed to be what. Also: there may not be an entirely bulletproof (/"proven") way to do this, but there may be some other (better) way to accomplish what you're trying to use a function to do. So please include more information about your actual goal (see: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

Comment: @user15762223 : Is there a reason why you define `liveLogs` etc. as function, and not as an executable script? Functions live in the process space of that shell process which defines them, and on the remote host, you have of course a different process.

Comment: @user1934428 : I agree with you and originally have already tried keeping the functions in separate .sh scripts. Calling them in wrapper script is straightforward and works fine.
On your question for why I am defining functions -> let's just say it's a requirement by stakeholders to have single script for everything.

Comment: You **can** have a single script, implementing many features. Just provide a parameter to choose the respective functionality. In this case your script contains all the function it needs; you just don't invoke them from the outside via the function name, but by choosing a certain parameter (command line option). You could also regard it as 'sub-command', similar like `git` is doing it, where you say `git pull` or `git merge`, depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I invoke the functions in ssh command as per the code mentioned in my revised post? I have tried calling function directly and also by assigning them to variables. In both cases it fails to work with SSH command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the *function definition* with all other context needed to the child process. With the following method, you are always safe:

```
if [[ $1 == "ARCHIVE" ]]
then
   func="archiveLogs" # --> assigning function __NAME__ to varibale
else
   func="liveLogs" # --> assigning function __NAME__ to varibale
fi

# It's easier to write a function, cause you can handle quoting easier.
some_entrypoint() {
     # Properly escape all variables
     "$func" "$ID"
}

ssh -q -T username@host "bash -s" <<EOF 2>&1 | tee -a ${OutputLogFilePath}
# Pass all functions that you will need
$(declare -f liveLogs archiveLogs some_entrypoint)
# Pass all variables that you need
$(declare -p func ID)
# Start your function
some_entrypoint
# You could use variable here, but proper "\$quoting" is painfull
# it's easier to write an entry function
EOF
```

Do not use `function liveLogs(){`. Prefer just `liveLogs() {`.

Comment: thanks @KamilCuk, but still i could not get it to work for me. Please see my answer where I have put the piece of main block code for better understanding.